# Mysterious "Long" DisplayType

Tags: metadata, fields, schema

I'm trying to figure out what "Long" DisplayType is (it's listed in [Schema.DisplayType Enum values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm)). I've checked standard fields for a couple of SF standard objects but didn't find any field with "Long" display type. In addition I did a few tries to create custom fields of different types to see if any of them would have "Long" display type - no results either.

Has anyone seen SF fields with that display type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the following anon apex on a scratch org and found two cases where this is used:

```
Set<Schema.DisplayType> displayTypes = new Set<Schema.DisplayType>();

Map<String,SObjectType> stuff = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

for (SObjectType theType : stuff.values()) {
    Map<String, SObjectField> theFields = theType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    
    for (SObjectField theField : theFields.values()) {
        displayTypes.add(theField.getDescribe().getType());
        
        if (theField.getDescribe().getType() == DisplayType.LONG) {
            System.debug('Type ' + theType.getDescribe().name + ' has long ' + theField.getDescribe().name);
        }
    }
}

for (DisplayType theType : displayTypes) {
    System.debug(theType);
}
```

The cases are:

```
08:46:36.38 (9071351018)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|Type AppAnalyticsQueryRequest has long DownloadSize
08:46:37.38 (10977321382)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|Type PlatformEventUsageMetric has long Value
```

I'd guess it is like integer but with more than 18 digits (which is what it normally is in primitive datatype terms). I note that the Setup UI doesn't allow creation of a Number with more than 18 digits to the left of the decimal place.